# CDN library blocked in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using leaflet/OSM for a small map on a site. The site itself is accessible via HTTPS while the leaflet library can (afaik) only be retrieved via a HTTP connection. Now Chrome doesn't include the library and gives me the following message in the console:

> ```
> [blocked] The page at https://example.com/foo/bar ran insecure content from http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.css_
> ```

Any idea how I could work around this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet/ has Leaflet. They have HTTPS version as well.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js
```

Use the above URLs in your code. The same protocol used to load the current page will be used to fetch Leaflet assets as well.

Comment: This will not work if you're using Leaflet from a secure website, since it will try to download it using HTTPS, and it looks like Leaflet's CDN isn't configured to handle HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the hosted version of leaflet, you can provide the necessary javascript and css files yourself: Just grab the latest version of leaflet at http://leafletjs.com/download.html and copy the directory "dist" to your project directory. After that you can change the links from "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/*" to "./dist/*".

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "http:" from your reference. try "//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.css". It will use the current page's protocol to send the request.

Comment: Looks leaflet doens't have a valid SSL certificate. You might try download the css to your own site. and add a https reference to it. Just FYI, Chrome blocks http resource download from a https site. http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/ending-mixed-scripting-vulnerabilities.html

Comment: Yeah, that's what I finally ended up with - see the answer from @tyr.

Answer (score 0):

Tiles are downloaded on CDN via HTTP, so there is little help in putting js/css in SSL