# My Javascript Files are not showing up on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, github, leaflet

I created a Leaflet Map, and uploaded the html and js file on Github. However, the map part is not showing up. Would appreciate any help on it. Here is the link below:

https://william-wang93.github.io/html/MedievalEngland/LeafletHeat.html

Answer (score 0):

These are the 2 links in your LeafletHeat.html file, if you try to open these link in the browser these require certificate thus browser is failing to fetch these files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Try replacing it with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
     crossorigin="">
```

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
     crossorigin=""></script>
```

You can refer the source for more information - https://openstreetmap.be/en/projects/howto/leaflet.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024655/behavior-of-js-css-from-unsecured-cdn and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018250/cdn-library-blocked-in-chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble like this but I was solved this by doing this:
Add close tag to script tag
Wrong path of javascript file
Try to change javascript name file to main.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).